# How do I combine these two different LINQ queries into one?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

How do I write this so that I can get the Id and the Fist and Last name all in one query? Everything I have found via Search is database related and involves a Join or a Group, which I don't think is applicable to what I am trying to do. I want to print the order Id and the associated first and last name to the screen.

```
   static void Main()
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(GetXml());

        var query = from el in document.Root.Elements("Order")
                    select new Orders
                    {
                        Id = (int)el.Element("Id")
                    };

        foreach (var cc in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cc.Id);

        }

        var info = from el in document.Root.Elements("Order").Elements("BillingAddress")
                   select new BillingAddress
                   {
                       FirstName = (string)el.Element("FirstName"),
                       LastName = (string)el.Element("LastName")
                   };

        foreach (var cc in info)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", cc.FirstName, cc.LastName);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    } 

    private static String GetXml()
    {
        return
            @"<ArrayOfOrder>
                <Order>
                    <Id>1</Id>
                    <OrderGuid />
                    <BillingAddress>
                        <FirstName>Harvey</FirstName>
                        <LastName>Danger</LastName>
                    </BillingAddress>
                </Order>
                <Order>
                    <Id>2</Id>
                    <OrderGuid />
                    <BillingAddress>
                        <FirstName>Brian</FirstName>
                        <LastName>Brakes</LastName>
                    </BillingAddress>
                </Order>
            </ArrayOfOrder>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `BillingAddress` property to your Orders class then you can do the following:

```
var query = from el in document.Root.Elements("Order")
            select new Orders
            {
                Id = (int) el.Element("Id"),
                BillingAddress = new BillingAddress
                {
                    FirstName = (string) el.Element("BillingAddress").Element("FirstName"),
                    LastName = (string) el.Element("BillingAddress").Element("LastName")
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from el in document.Root.Elements("Order")
                    select new Orders
                    {
                        Id = (int)el.Element("Id"),
                        Names = el.Elements("BillingAddress")
                                  .Select(ba=> 
                                        new { FirstName = (string)ba.Element("FirstName"),
                                              LastName = (string)ba.Element("LastName")
                                            }
                    };
```